# Sparql find entities with dbo type and sort them by count

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have to do a sparql query to the dbpedia endpoint which needs to:

1. Find all the entities containing "vienna" in the `label` and "city" in the `abstract`
2. Filter them keeping only the ones that have at least one `dbo` `rdf:type`
3. Sort the results by count of `dbo` types (e.g. if an entity has 5 `dbo` `rdf:type` it has to be shown before entities with 4 `dbo` `rdf:type`)

I did several attempts, the closest to the result is:

```
select distinct (str(?s) as ?s) count(?t) as ?total where {{ ?s rdfs:label "vienna"@en. ?s rdf:type ?t.} 
UNION { ?s rdfs:label ?l. ?s rdf:type ?t . ?l <bif:contains> '("vienna")'
. FILTER EXISTS { ?s dbo:abstract ?cc. ?cc <bif:contains> '("city")'. FILTER(lang(?cc) = "en").}} 
FILTER (!strstarts(str(?s), str("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:")))
. FILTER (!strstarts(str(?s), str("http://dbpedia.org/property/")))
. FILTER (!strstarts(str(?s), str("http://dbpedia.org/ontology/")))
. FILTER (strstarts(str(?t), str("http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"))).} 
LIMIT 50
```

Which will (wrongly) count the `rdf:type` before actually filtering it. I don't want to count `rdf:type` that are not `dbo` (ontology).

Comment: Use your current query as subquery to just get the entities and in the outer query you apply the `dbo` filter and count

Comment: by the way, right now in the first UNION part you don't apply the abstract filter. Look at your closing brackets. I guess the idea is to. Moreover, the `bif:contains` part also covers the literals with exactly matching `vienna`. And don't you need a language filter for the labels?  And isn't the `rdf:type` filter in both UNION parts redundant?

Comment: It should be more like this: `select distinct ?s where {
?s rdfs:label ?l. ?l <bif:contains> '("vienna")'
FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?l), "en")) ?s rdf:type ?t . 
FILTER EXISTS { ?s dbo:abstract ?cc. ?cc <bif:contains> '("city")'. FILTER(lang(?cc) = "en")}
FILTER (!strstarts(str(?s), str("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:")))
FILTER (!strstarts(str(?s), str("http://dbpedia.org/property/")))
FILTER (!strstarts(str(?s), str("http://dbpedia.org/ontology/")))
FILTER (strstarts(str(?t), str("http://dbpedia.org/ontology/")))} ` - and this use as subquery and in the outer query you can count

Comment: Something like this: https://tools.wmflabs.org/paste/view/6973f170

Comment: Thanks @AKSW exactly what I needed. You can post it as answer, there is a mismatched round bracket (need closing) in the paste in the LANGMATCHES filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a subquery in which you search for the entities and to do the counting in the outer query:

```sql
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT  ?s (count(*) AS ?cnt)
WHERE
  { { SELECT DISTINCT  ?s
      WHERE
        { ?s  rdfs:label      ?l .
          ?l  <bif:contains>  '"vienna"'
          FILTER langMatches(lang(?l), "en")
          FILTER EXISTS { ?s   dbo:abstract    ?cc .
                          ?cc  <bif:contains>  '"city"'
                          FILTER langMatches(lang(?cc), "en")
                        }
          ?s  rdf:type  ?t
          FILTER ( ! strstarts(str(?s), str("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:")) )
          FILTER ( ! strstarts(str(?s), str("http://dbpedia.org/property/")) )
          FILTER ( ! strstarts(str(?s), str(dbo:)) )
          FILTER strstarts(str(?t), str(dbo:))
        }
    }
    ?s  ?p  ?o
    FILTER strstarts(str(?p), str(dbo:))
  }
GROUP BY ?s
ORDER BY DESC(?cnt)
```